# Easy way to do operations on Java Files?

Tags: java, database

I am new to Java and
I am trying to read a text file so that I can do operations on it (delete column etc.). 
Consider an example file

```
Name,Cats,Dogs
Paul,1,3
Julia,2,4
```

So far, I am using `Scanner` to read the `file`. To do operations I wanted to use `ArrayList`:

```
File temp = new File("Path-to-file");
Scanner s;
try{
s=new Scanner(temp);
ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
while(s.hasNextLine()){
list.add(s.nextLine());
}
s.close();
} catch (FileNotFoundException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Now, I could do some operations, e.g. remove a row with the remove method. But it is not exactly what I am looking for. It is really complicated (for me as a beginner in Java...) to return for example the column 'Dogs'. I would have to identify the index of the column dogs and then run through all rows. Isn't there an easier way for handling data in Java?

Comment: use Map instead of ArrayList, use key as column name and values as list of record for that specific column.

Comment: Actually, this is exactly the task a database is predestined for - well, you tagged the question as such... SQLite might be and option for you if you do not want to install a real dbms (PostgreSQL, MySQL, ...). Just google "sqlite java" and you get dozens of sites providing information...

Comment: I'll share the example, from java side

Answer (score 1):

To read all lines, there is a newer way to do it:

```
Path path = Paths.get("Path-to-file");
List<String> lines = Files.readAllLines(path, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
```

Here I indicated the encoding of the bytes of the file. UTF-8 can do all Unicode, so is an apt choice. The file then must be saved as UTF-8.

If you know the structure and want to do some business logic for that specific subject:

```
class Person {
    String name;
    int cats;
    int dogs;
}

List<Person> persons = new ArrayList<>();
lines.remove(0); // Remove header line with index 0
for (String line : lines) {
    Person person = new Person();
    String[] parts = line.split(",", 3);
    person.name = parts[0];
    person.cats = Integer.parseInt(parts[1]);
    person.dogs = Integer.parseInt(parts[2]);
    persons.add(person);
}

for (Person person : persons) {
    System.out.printf("%s has %d cats and %d dogs.%n",
            person.name, person.cats, person.dogs);
}

// Java 8 streams (= walk throughs)
persons.stream()
    .filter(pers -> pers.cats == 0)
    .sort((pers1, pers2) -> Integer.compare(pers1.dogs, pers2.dogs))
    .forEach((pers) -> System.out.printf("%s has %d dogs.%n", pers.name, pers.dogs));
```

Otherwise you could use a CSV (comma-separated-values) library and do Excel like things.

Answer (score 0):

Like Joop said, you can use also a library, a good one you can download from [CsvEngine Library](https://github.com/ybonnel/CsvEngine/wiki/Install) and import to your project.

Later you have to define a class for your file...

```
import fr.ybonnel.csvengine.annotation.CsvColumn;
import fr.ybonnel.csvengine.annotation.CsvFile;

@CsvFile(separator = ",")
class Person {

    @CsvColumn("Name")
    public String name;

    @CsvColumn("Cats")
    public int cats;

    @CsvColumn("Dogs")
    public int dogs;

    // Generate getters and setters ...
}
```

Later you have to create a class to be able to read your file...

```
import java.io.InputStream;
import fr.ybonnel.csvengine.CsvEngine;
import fr.ybonnel.csvengine.exception.CsvErrorsExceededException;

public class CsvReaderExample<T> {

    private static CsvEngine engine;
    private Class<T> clazz;

    public CsvReaderExample(Class<T> clazz) {
        this.clazz = clazz;
        engine = new CsvEngine(clazz);
    }

    public List<T> readObjects(InputStream inputStreamFile) throws CsvErrorsExceededException, IOException {
        return engine.parseInputStream(inputStreamFile, clazz).getObjects();
    }   
}
```

And then you call it...

```
CsvReaderExample<Person> csvEngine = new CsvReaderExample<>(Person.class);
List<Person> persons = csvEngine.readObjects(YourFileLikeInputStream);
```

If you want to learn more how to use this library. You can read the [Wiki of the Library](https://github.com/ybonnel/CsvEngine/wiki)